# ServiceStack Json deserializing incorrectely

Tags: c#, servicestack

I've got a RequestDto, let's say Class A Dto, it contains a self defined type property:

```
// C# code
public Class MyObject
{
    public string A { get; set; }
    public string B { get; set; }
}
public Class ADto
{
    public List<MyObject> MO { get; set;}
}
```

When I am trying to send the Dto using Json, the Json object looks like this:

```
{"MO":[{"A":"String","B":"a"},{"A":"String","B":"b"}]}
```

but the object I am receiving will be null.
However if I change the Json string into:

```
{MO:[{A:"String",B:"a"},{A:"String",B:"b"}]}
```

I lose the quotation marks on the objects' names and it works.
The correct format of Json should include those quotation marks right?
Why is this happening?

Comment: Can you share the code that you are using for serialization / de serialization?

Comment: It is standard library on various clients(iOS, Android). I tried this Json string using Postman, the result is as described.

Comment: Your class says you have two properties called A and B. But your Json says you have two properties called "Mobile" and "Name". That does not look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceStack does serializes and deserializes valid JSON which requires [every property name to be quoted](http://www.json.org/) however you're saying that the text below works:

```
{MO:[{A:"String",B:"a"},{A:"String",B:"b"}]}
```

However this isn't valid JSON, it instead looks like [ServiceStack's JSV Format](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/wiki/JSV-Format)

You haven't mentioned where you're sending the JSV Format or have provided the Raw HTTP Request (for us to work it out), but I'm assuming if you're using Postman (mentioned in your comments) than you're trying to send JSON in the `?QueryString` which isn't allowed.

But ServiceStack does support sending [complex object graphs on the QueryString using JSV](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Serialization-deserialization#passing-complex-objects-in-the-query-string).

Since you're sending a complex type you'd either **POST** the request as either **JSON** or **www-form-urlencoded** Form Data or if you want to pass it in the QueryString you need to convert it to JSV.

In future please include the Raw HTTP Request as this question lacks any context on where you're changing the JSON string, how you're trying to use it or what's actually being sent, where you're sending it to, etc - making it impossible to guess what the issue is.

Comment: Thanks, mythz. After reading your answer, I realized that I didn't quite understand how data is send using through HTTP request. Using Postman to send data, I can choose to use form-data, x-www-form-urlenencoded or raw. I think I should send the JSON data in the raw section. You are right about providing the Raw HTTP Request, but also I think the reason my question was too vague is that I didn't quite understand what I was doing, I assumed sending form-data is the same as sending JSON. Thanks again.

Comment: Problem solved. It is because that I POST the request as form data rather than JSON. I wish I could up vote your answer, but I am new and not allowed to up vote any answer yet.

Comment: @gnaix np glad I could help :) you should still be able to accept answers right?

Answer (score 0):

Change your class to

```
public Class MyObject
{
    public string Mobile { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
public Class ADto
{
    public List<MyObject> MO { get; set;}
}
```

Then your json should be

```
{MO:[{Mobile:"0556604",Name:"Peter"},{Mobile:"4565466",Name:"John"}]}
```

Comment: that's not valid JSON, [each property name needs to be quoted](http://www.json.org/);

Comment: Yes. Proper formatting would be {"MO":[{"Mobile":"0556604","Name":"Peter"},{"Mobile":"4565466","Name":"John"}]}